# XML Schema for an XML representation of CSV

Tags: xml, xsd, xslt

This is intended to be part of a generalised solution to the problem of converting any (with some minor restrictions) CSV content into XML. The restrictions on the CSV, and the purpose of the schema should be apparent from the annotations.

The main review criteria I request are:

1. Is it suitable for non-destructive round-trip transformations from .csv to .xml and back again to .csv?
2. Is the schema clear and readable enough?
3. Is there a simpler way to do the same thing?
4. Are there any obvious errors?

This schema, as well as associated XSLT style-sheets, when polished, will be put to good use in the public domain with a creative commons license.

Here is the schema to be reviewed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xcsv="http://seanbdurkin.id.au/xslt/xcsv.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://seanbdurkin.id.au/xslt/xcsv.xsd"
    version="1.0">

  <xs:import
      namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" 
      schemaLocation="xml.xsd"/>

  <xs:element name="comma-separated-single-line-values">
   <xs:annotation><xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
    This schema describes an XML representation of a subset of csv content.
    The format described by this schema, here-after referred to as "xcsv"
    is part of a generalised solution to the problem of converting
    general csv files into suitable XML, and the reverse transform.

    The restrictions on the csv content are:
      * The csv file is encoded either in UTF-8 or UTF16. If UTF-16, a BOM
        is required.
      * The cell values of the csv may not contain the CR or LF characters.
        Essentially, we are restricted to single-line values.

    The xcsv format was developed by Sean B. Durkin&#x85;
    www.seanbdurkin.id.au
   </xs:documentation></xs:annotation>

   <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>

     <xs:element ref="xcsv:notice" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
     <xs:element name="row" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:annotation><xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
       A row element represents a "row" or "line" in the csv file. Rows contain values.
       </xs:documentation>
       <xs:appinfo>
        <example>
         <csv-line>apple,"banana","red, white and blue","quote this("")"</csv-line>
         <row>
          <value>apple</value>
          <value>banana</value>
          <value>red, white and blue</value>
          <value>quote this(")</value>
         </row>
        </example>
       </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation> 
        <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <xs:annotation><xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
         Empty rows are not possible in csv. We must have at least one value or one error.
       </xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
       <xs:element name="value">
        <xs:annotation><xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
         A value element represents a decoded (model) csv "value" or "cell".
         If the encoded value in the lexical csv was of a quoted form, then
         the element content here is the decoded or model form. In other words,
         the delimiting double-quote marks are striped out and the internal
         escaped double-quotes are de-escaped.
        </xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
        <xs:simpleType>
         <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:pattern value="[^\n]*"/>
          <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
          <xs:annotation><xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
           Cell values must fit this pattern because of the single-line restriction
           that we placed on the csv values.
          </xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
         </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
       </xs:element>
       <xs:group ref="xcsv:errorGroup">
        <xs:annotation><xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
          An error can be recorded here as a child of row, if there was an encoding
          error in the csv for that row.
        </xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
       </xs:group>
        </xs:choice>
     </xs:element>

     <xs:group ref="xcsv:errorGroup">
      <xs:annotation><xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
       An error can be recorded here as a child of the comma-separated-values element,
       if there was an i/o error in the transformational process. For example:
        CSV file not found.
      </xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
     </xs:group>

    </xs:sequence>

    <xs:attribute name="xcsv-version" type="xs:decimal"
        fixed="1.0" use="required"/>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="comma-separated-multiline-values">
   <xs:annotation><xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
    Similar to xcsv:comma-separated-multi-line-values but allows multi-line values.
   </xs:documentation></xs:annotation>

   <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>

     <xs:element ref="xcsv:notice" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
     <xs:element name="row" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <xs:element name="value">
        <xs:simpleType>
         <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
         </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
       </xs:element>
       <xs:group ref="xcsv:errorGroup">
       </xs:group>
        </xs:choice>
     </xs:element>

     <xs:group ref="xcsv:errorGroup">
     </xs:group>

    </xs:sequence>

    <xs:attribute name="xcsv-version" type="xs:decimal"
        fixed="1.0" use="required"/>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

 <xs:element name="notice" type="xcsv:notice-en" />
      <xs:annotation><xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
       This is an optional element below comma-separated-single-line-values or
        comma-separated-multiline-values that looks like the example.
       </xs:documentation>
      <xs:appinfo>
       <example>
        <notice xml:lang="en">The xcsv format was developed by Sean B. Durkin&#x85;www.seanbdurkin.id.au</notice>
       </example>
      </xs:appinfo></xs:annotation>
      <xs:complexType name="notice-en">
        <xs:simpleContent>
          <xs:extension base="xcsv:notice-content-en">
           <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang" use="required" fixed="en" />
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleType name="notice-content-en">
       <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:enumeration value="The xcsv format was developed by Sean B. Durkin&#x85;www.seanbdurkin.id.au"/>
       </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
 <xs:element />

   <xs:group name="errorGroup">
      <xs:annotation><xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
       This is an error node/message in one or more languages.
      </xs:documentation>
      <xs:appinfo>
       <example>
        <error error-code="2">
         <message xml:lang="en">Quoted value not terminated.</message>
         <message xml:lang="ru">Цитируется значение не прекращается.</message>
         <error-data>"</error-data>
        </error>
       </example> 
       <example>
        <error error-code="3">
         <message xml:lang="en">Quoted value incorrectly terminated.</message>
         <message xml:lang="ru">Цитируется значение неправильно прекращено.</message>
        </error>
       </example>
      </xs:appinfo> 
      </xs:annotation>
   <xs:element name="error">
    <xs:element name="message" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xcsv:string-with-lang" />
      <xs:annotation><xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
       Although there can be multiple messages, there should only be at most one per language.
      </xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
    <xs:element name="error-data" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" >
     <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
      </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:attribute name="error-code" type="xs:positiveInteger" default="1" />
      <xs:annotation><xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
       Each different kind of error should be associated with a unique error code.
       A map for the error codes is outside the scope of this schema, except to say the following:
         * one (1) means a general or uncategorised error. (Try to avoid this!)
      </xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
   </xs:element>
  </xs:group>

  <xs:complexType name="string-with-lang">
      <xs:annotation><xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
       This is an element with text content in some language as indicated
       by the xml:lang attribute.
      </xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
   <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
     <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang" use="required" default="en" />
    </xs:extension>
   </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>


</xs:schema>
```

**Use cases**

**Case 1**

Lines ending in CR LF, including the last line.

The CSV:

```
1st name,2nd name
Sean,Brendan,"Durkin"
""","""
<This is a place-marker for an empty row>
"",
```

The XML equivalent (schema valid):

```
<xcsv:comma-separated-values
    xmlns:xcsv="http://seanbdurkin.id.au/xslt/xcsv.xsd"
    xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
    xcsv-version="1.0">
 <xcsv:notice xml:lang="en">The xcsv format was developed by Sean B. Durkin&#x85;www.seanbdurkin.id.au</xcsv:notice>
 <xcsv:row>
  <xcsv:value>1st name</xcsv:value> <xcsv:value>2nd name</xcsv:value>
 </xcsv:row>
 <xcsv:row>
  <xcsv:value>Sean</xcsv:value> <xcsv:value>Brendan</xcsv:value> <xcsv:value>Durkin</xcsv:value>
 </xcsv:row>
 <xcsv:row>
  <xcsv:value>","</xcsv:value>
 </xcsv:row>
 <xcsv:row>
  <xcsv:value />
 </xcsv:row>
 <xcsv:row>
  <xcsv:value /> <xcsv:value />
 </xcsv:row>
</xcsv:comma-separated-values>
```

**Case 2**

As case 1, but with line endings as just LF.

XML as case 1.

**Case 3**

Lines ending in CR LF, including the last line.

The CSV:

```
Fruit,Colour
Banana,Yellow
```

The XML equivalent (schema valid):

```
<xcsv:comma-separated-values
    xmlns:xcsv="http://seanbdurkin.id.au/xslt/xcsv.xsd"
    xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
    xcsv-version="1.0">
 <xcsv:row>
  <xcsv:value>Fruit</xcsv:value> <xcsv:value>Colour</xcsv:value>
 </xcsv:row>
 <xcsv:row>
  <xcsv:value>Banana</xcsv:value> <xcsv:value>Yellow</xcsv:value>
 </xcsv:row>
</xcsv:comma-separated-values>
```

**Case 4**

Same as case 3, but last line ends in eof. In other words, the last byte of the file is the UTF-8 code for 'w'.

Same XML!

**Case 5**

Empty file. The size of the file is zero.

Valid XML instance:

```
<xcsv:comma-separated-values
 xmlns:xcsv="http://seanbdurkin.id.au/xslt/xcsv.xsd"
 xcsv-version="1.0" />
```

**Case 6.**

The file has one byte: the UTF-8 code for LF.

CSV:

```
LF
```

Valid XML instance:

Same XML as case 5!

**Case 7**

CVS encoding errors

The CSV (not valid):

```
Fruit,"Colour
Banana,"Yell"ow
```

The valid XML instance:

```
<xcsv:comma-separated-values
    xmlns:xcsv="http://seanbdurkin.id.au/xslt/xcsv.xsd"
    xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
    xcsv-version="1.0">
 <xcsv:row>
  <xcsv:value>Fruit</xcsv:value>

  <xcsv:error error-code="2">
   <xcsv:message xml:lang="en">Quoted value not terminated.</xcsv:message>
   <xcsv:error-data>"</xcsv:error-data>
  </xcsv:error>

  <xcsv:value>Colour</xcsv:value>
 </xcsv:row>
 <xcsv:row>
  <xcsv:value>Banana</xcsv:value>

  <xcsv:error error-code="3">
   <xcsv:message xml:lang="en">Quoted value incorrectly terminated.</xcsv:message>
   <xcsv:error-data>"</xcsv:error-data>
  </xcsv:error>

  <xcsv:value>Yell"ow</xcsv:value>
 </xcsv:row>
</xcsv:comma-separated-values>
```

**Case 8**

Specific application where CSV looks like:

```
1st name,2nd name
Sean,Durkin
"Peter","Pan"
```

In this specific application, the header is always there, with columns in the specified order:

```
<people>
 <person first-name="Sean" first-name="Durkin" />
 <person first-name="Peter" first-name="Pan" />
</people>
```

1. Step 1.  Transform .cvs into .xcvs, using a generic library XSLT style-sheet.
2. Step 2.  Transform .xcsv into the application-specific  structure as above, using a trivial XSLT style-sheet.

**Case 9**

This use case demonstrates the necessary XML encoding on a lexical level for & and < and raw data. No special encoding is required at the XML parser API level.

The CSV:

```
 Character,Name
 &,Ampersand
 <,Less than
```

The equivalent schema-valid XML instance:

```
<xcsv:comma-separated-values
    xmlns:xcsv="http://seanbdurkin.id.au/xslt/xcsv.xsd"
    xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
    xcsv-version="1.0">
 <xcsv:row>
  <xcsv:value>Character</xcsv:value> <xcsv:value>Name</xcsv:value>
 </xcsv:row>
 <xcsv:row>
  <xcsv:value>&amp;</xcsv:value> <xcsv:value>Ampersand</xcsv:value>
 </xcsv:row>
 <xcsv:row>
  <xcsv:value>&lt;</xcsv:value> <xcsv:value>Less than</xcsv:value>
 </xcsv:row>
</xcsv:comma-separated-values>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This is more of a comment, than an answer, but there are several longer points I'd like to address which is easier in an answer).

Could you show some use cases for this? Considering that both CSV and XML are both formats for general data storage, I don't see point in converting as CSV file into a "non-specifc" XML format instead directly into the "specific" XML format of the application in use.

Also, the problem with CSV is that it's not really standardized. Despite the name they don't need to use commas as value separators. Semicolons or tabs are common variants. Also some variants require quoting all values, or allow single quotes, or use backslashes to escape quotes in values, or allow line breaks in values (which is the one variant you curiously disallow). If you really need "non-destructive round-trip transformations" you should consider all these variants and store the "features" of the CSV implementation in your XML.

On the other hand, you store the information if a value is quoted or not, but this isn't really part of the "relevant information". Take a, for example, similar "conversation": XML -> DOM -> XML. Here it is also not stored if or how a value is quoted. An XML document such as

```
<example><![CDATA[ <&> ]]></example>
```

after reading it into a DOM structure and then re-serializing it, it could (and often would) come out as:

```
<example> &lt;&amp;&gt; </example>
```

because both encodings are equivalent.

Similarly in your case, it shouldn't matter if a value was originally quoted or not. So if a row such as

```
"apple","banana","red, white and blue","quote this("")"
```

come out as

```
apple,banana,"red, white and blue","quote this("")"
```

should be irrelevant - unless the specific CSV application requires quoting. So it's more important to store *that* information in the XML, than whether or a single value was quoted or not.

Comment: Thanks for that RoToRa. You put some really good points and questions. I will respond fully over the weekend. I will include use cases and rationales.

Comment: It was a good point that I should specify Use Cases. Please find a collection of Use Cases following.

Comment: To explain the value of a generic XML format, consider the situation where one is required to convert an specific csv format into a specific XML format using XSLT 2+ . Without a generic format, you can do it. It is not a big problem, but there is a certain non-zero cost to develop the
 XSLT. ....

Comment: With a generic format, one could handle the transformation in two phases. The first phase
from generic csv to generic xml using a stock standard library XSLT script. Since this is a pre-made
library routine, the cost of this phase is zero. The second phase would be to convert the generic
XML to the application-specific XML. Again, there is some non-zero cost involved. So both paths
have a cost. The relevant question is which is the lower cost. .....

Comment: The theory that I propose, and the
need-driver for this schema, is the idea that cost of developing a transform from generic XML
to a specific XML, in XSLT, is a lot cheaper and simpler than developing a direct single-pass transform
from a specific csv to a specific XML. Well is it really true? I guess if you are not convinced
the real test would be giving an example use case of a csv to xml problem, and showing two solutions:
One direct single-pass, and the other two-pass using a generic xml format (xcsv) in the middle. ....

Comment: ... I will make this demonstration/proof/disproof and attach it or reference it to the schema when I
finish polishing the schema and publish it.

Comment: I think you are right about round-trip. Only the real pay-load data of the csv or xml files
matters and not its lexical representation. Looking back, I can't see much value in trying to
preserve bit-for-bit identicality in a round-trip transformation. Its like the difference between
single quotes and double quotes in an XML attribute delimiter - It shouldn't matter.....

Comment: ... Therefore I 
will drop the "xcsv:quoted" attribute from the "xcsv:value" element, as it now appears to be an
unnecessary complexity....

Comment: Upon reflection, I think I should also remove the name-space qualification from the domestic attributes, to bring the schema more in line with common practice.

Comment: Why did I exclude Line-breaking csv from the scope? CSV is an extremily broad format with no commonly
recognised standard. The schema was designed with an XSLT 2 & 3 transformation solution in mind.
It is just too hard a problem to generically solve the conversion problem with multi-line in XSLT
with any kind of reasonable efficiency for large files. ....

Comment: ... The problem would have been even more difficult
if I expanded to scope to include any kind of character encoding or any kind of value separator
(such as dots, pipes, space, tabs etc). I made the compromise of limiting the scope of the problem
definition for the practical purposes of being able to offer an attactive generic practical efficient XSLT 2/3
solution which meets the schema. ...

Comment: ... Having said that, I am not at all confident that I made the right
compromise here. It would be possible to remove the no-line-breaks restriction from the value cell
of the schema, and then the schema would be just as usefull for two different csv-to-xml transformations:
one fast one with scope limited to single line values, and another broader one that can include
multi-line values. After all, a Schema is not necessarily tied to any particular transform....

Comment: ... So I leave
this question ("was limiting the scope to single-line values a good idea") unresolved, except to say
that I want to collect more opinions on the matter.